# Informing Sentry about the latest release version in GitHub

Tags: github-actions

I am using the [getsentry/action-release@v1](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/sentry-release) GitHub Action to inform Sentry about new releases in my GitHub application. However, since I am using tags as the version number, I would like to inform sentry about the latest tag available on the release page. I'm having issues doing that while using environment variables.

Here is my job:

```
  inform_sentry_about_release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set GITHUB_VERSION variable
        run: |
          echo 'GITHUB_LATEST_RELEASE=$(curl -H "Authorization: token ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" "https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/myreponame/releases" -s | jq -r ".[0].tag_name")' >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Create Sentry release
        uses: getsentry/action-release@v1
        env:
          SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN }}
          SENTRY_ORG: ${{ secrets.SENTRY_ORG }}
          SENTRY_PROJECT: ${{ secrets.SENTRY_PROJECT }}
        with:
          environment: production
          version: ${{ GITHUB_LATEST_RELEASE }}
```

My Github workflow is failing with the following error:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/production-label.yml (Line: 131, Col: 20): Unrecognized named-value: 'GITHUB_LATEST_RELEASE'. Located at position 1 within expression: GITHUB_LATEST_RELEASE
```

According to [How do I dynamically set an environment variable in a github composite action step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70370971/how-do-i-dynamically-set-an-environment-variable-in-a-github-composite-action-st), it appears that I should be able to just echo a key=val to the `GITHUB_ENV` and then call it in the next step, but no luck.

Line 131 specifically refers to this:

```
version: ${{ GITHUB_LATEST_RELEASE }}
```

Is there a different way I'm supposed to access this environment variable from this line? I've tried $GITHUB_LATEST_RELEASE and still no luck with that either.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable should be accessed in the following way:

```yaml
version: ${{ env.GITHUB_LATEST_RELEASE }}
```

Please note, that the names of environment variables are case-sensitive, and you can include punctuation.

**Example:**

```
steps:
  - name: Set the value
    id: step_one
    run: |
      echo "action_state=yellow" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  - name: Use the value
    id: step_two
    run: |
      echo "${{ env.action_state }}" # This will output 'yellow'
```

For more information check the [Setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable).